# How i download a string base64 in javascript using internet explorer browser

Tags: javascript, html, file, base64

Hi i am trying to download a base64 using the internet explorer browser but when i am clicking the link, the console of the browser pop up the next error "The data area transferred to a system call is too small."

Is there another form to download the document, if there is it can you share the code please?

Let me share my code. Note: The base64 string is incomplete

```
<DOCTYPE!html>

    <script>

   var pdf = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' +
    'JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu'; 

   window.downloadPDF = function downloadPDF() {

    var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
    dlnk.href = pdf;

    dlnk.click();


    alert('toma');
}

    </script>

    <body>

    <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding:100px;">

        <a id='dwnldLnk' download='base64file.pdf' style="display:none;" /> 

        <a href="#" onclick="downloadPDF();" title='base64file.pdf'>click to download</a>

    </div>

    <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't you just host the pdf file and use `<a/>` with its href in the page? To store it as base64 in an html page looks like a pretty weird way to do this...

Comment: sjhan can you share me a better solution. Thanks